# Bash Date error between 0 to 1 am

Tags: bash, date, hour

I'm working on bash and date values, now I have a problem when the hours are between 00 to 00:59:59, bash give me a 'invalid date error'

How can I work with thats values?

Ex:

```
date --date="2014/09/07 00:59:00" +%H
date: invalid date ‘2014/09/07 00:59:00’
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What does `date --version` return? (first line only, the rest should be fluff)

Comment: This doesn't reproduce for me.  Are you sure you don't have a typo or something?

Comment: Probably not relevant, but the international standard date format (ISO 8601) is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 3):

In your timezone (check the $TZ variable), there was a switch between daylight saving time and normal time. The hour you specified was skipped and never existed.

cf.

```
TZ=America/Godthab date --date="2013-03-30T22:32:00.000"
```

taken from [The time that never was](http://beust.com/weblog/2013/03/30/the-time-that-never-was/).